# How to make animated websites with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hve seen a couple of really cool websites that are animated with javascript.  Google have done a few animated interactive logos and [this](http://www.volll.com/#section_main) site too is animated with javascript (not the flash bit clearly).

Well how to do it?  Is there some tool, framework etc that people use?  I only know of jquery.

Comment: Check out the `<canvas>` tag for non-flash animations.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704703/getting-started-with-canvas-html5

Answer (score 2):

Here's the rulebook: http://api.jquery.com/animate

Here's the playground: http://jsfiddle.net

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is the best framework to use as a base. It handles all the cross-browser idiosyncrasies.

Check out jQuery UI.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/

Answer (score 0):

If your audience is newer, you should also consider **[CSS 3 Transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/)**.

```
 .animated {
   transition: all 0.3s linear;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;  
   -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
 }
```

Changing a style property for any element with this class will transition to its new property.  E.g. adjusting "margin-left" from 0px to 100px will cause a slide to the right; adjusting "background-color" from "red" to "blue" will cause a cool color-change effect.  Give it a go!

For browser compatibility, check out [caniuse-- transitions](http://caniuse.com/#search=transitions).  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer SVG for interactive graphics, if you prefer Vector Graphics. I would suggest using Adobe Illustrator or something similar to produce the graphics and then use [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) to animate it. If you want a really good introduction, go for the really good [PeepCode Episode](http://peepcode.com/products/raphaeljs).

Answer (score 0):

From examining their source it looks like volll rolled their own method of animation using javascript.

If you want to make graphical animations on your own site I would suggest having a look at the HTML5 canvas tag.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial